# C++ calling perl code - eval_sv not passing arguments to script

Tags: c++, perl, xs

I have the below sample program which pushes the arguments to Perl stack and then calls "eval_sv". The sample perl statements get executed but i'm not able to retrieve the variables passed from C++ as Perl arguments. Please let me know what i am missing in the below program

**Output of the program**

> Hello World
>
> Test
>
> 100Testing complete

This line doesn't print the value of $a and $b

```
string three = "print 'Test\n'; my $z = 100; print $a; print $b; print $z;";
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <EXTERN.h>
#include <perl.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
  
string perlScript;

static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;

SV* my_eval_sv(I32 croak_on_error)
{
    STRLEN n_a;
    char *p1 = new char [perlScript.size()+1];
    strcpy(p1, perlScript.c_str());
    const char *p = p1;
    int len = strlen(p);

    dSP;
    ENTER ;
    SAVETMPS ;
    PUSHMARK(SP) ;


    int a, b;
    a = 10;
    b = 20;

    PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(a)));
    PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
    XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(b)));


    /* Done with pushing pointers to Perl stack */

    PUTBACK;

    SV* sv1 = newSVpv(p, 0);    
    eval_sv(sv1, G_EVAL | G_KEEPERR);
    SvREFCNT_dec(sv1);

    SPAGAIN;
    sv1 = POPs;
    PUTBACK;

    FREETMPS;
    LEAVE;

    if (croak_on_error && SvTRUE(ERRSV))
        croak(SvPVx(ERRSV, n_a));   
}

main (int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    char *embedding[] = { "", "-e", "0" };
    PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc,&argv,&env);
    my_perl = perl_alloc();
    perl_construct(my_perl);
    perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, 3, embedding, NULL);
    PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;
   
    /*string perlBeginScript;
    static const char * perlEndScript = "\
                                 \n\
    }\n\
    ";

    if(perlBeginScript.length()==0)
    {
        perlBeginScript="EmbeddedPerl";
    }

    perlScript = "sub ";
    perlScript += perlBeginScript;
    perlScript += "{\n"; */

    string one = "print 'Hello World\n'; ";
    string two = "my $a = shift; my $b = shift; ";
    string three= "print 'Test\n'; my $z = 100; print $a; print $b; print $z;";
    string four = "print 'Testing complete\n';";

    perlScript += one ;
    perlScript += two;
    perlScript += three;
    perlScript += four;

    //perlScript += perlEndScript;

    /* Done with perl script to be executed */
    my_eval_sv(TRUE);
    PL_perl_destruct_level = 1;
    perl_destruct(my_perl);
    perl_free(my_perl);
    PERL_SYS_TERM(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just guessing here...

You try to pass some values to your Perl code by putting them on the Perl stack and then you expect the `shift` calls to retrieve values from the stack.

Depending on scope `shift` uses `@_` or `@ARGV` and neither are interchangeable with "the stack". Only by making a perl subroutine call `@_` is populated with elements from the stack. This is done with the `call_sv` function described in the [perlcall](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html#THE-CALL_-FUNCTIONS) manualpage.

In your case `shift` is not called from inside a subroutine, so it tries to shift from `@ARGV`. But as this array is empty your variables will be set to `undef` which is consistent with the output you are getting.

If you need to pass arguments I would recommend to write your Perl code as a anonymous subrouting. That is eval you subroutine definition with `eval_pv()` and then call it with `call_sv()` after setting up the stack. The commented out sections of you code seems to indicate that you have looked at this approach (but with a named subroutine).

Alternatively you need to push your arguments to `@ARGV` by retireving it with `get_av`and then perform the appropriate operations on it. Though I am not sure if `@ARGV`is magic in any way.

Comment: You are correct @pmakholm. Perl documentation on [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) tells this exactly as you described: _If ARRAY is omitted, shifts the @_ array within the lexical scope of subroutines and formats, and the @ARGV array outside a subroutine and also within the lexical scopes established by the eval STRING..._

Comment: On second thought, the difference in which array `shift` tries to access isn't the main problem. The main issue is that neither of them is tied directly to the stack where @yogishaj places the values. So I've added a section about the relation between the stack and `@_`

Comment: @pmakholm I could resolve the problem with your inputs. I'm new to using Perl APIs. I used the combination "eval_sv" and "call_pv" and my program works.

        croak_on_error = eval_sv(sv1, G_EVAL | G_KEEPERR);  
        cout << "croak on error is" << croak_on_error << endl; 

        call_pv("Test", G_KEEPERR | G_EVAL);

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the above program posted in the question to make it work with inputs from @pmakholm.

```
#include <EXTERN.h>
#include <perl.h>
#include <string>


#undef do_open
#undef do_close
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


string perlScript;

static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;

SV* my_eval_sv(I32 croak_on_error)
{

    STRLEN n_a; 


char *p1 = new char [perlScript.size()+1];
strcpy(p1, perlScript.c_str());
const char *p = p1;
int len = strlen(p);

dSP;
ENTER ;
SAVETMPS ;
PUSHMARK(SP) ;


int a, b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l;
a = 900;
b = 1000;
    c = 2000;
    d = 3000;
    e = 4000;
    f = 5000;
    g = 6000;
    h =7000;
    i=8000;
    k=9000;
    l=10000;


PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(a)));
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(b))); 
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(c)));
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(d))); 
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(e)));
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(f)));
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(g))); 
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(h))); 
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(i))); 
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(j))); 
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(k))); 
PERL_SET_CONTEXT(my_perl);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSViv(l))); 


    /* Done with pushing pointers to Perl stack */

PUTBACK;

SV* sv1 = newSVpv(p, 0);

croak_on_error = eval_sv(sv1, G_EVAL | G_KEEPERR);  
    cout << "croak on error is" << croak_on_error << endl; 

    call_pv("Test", G_KEEPERR | G_EVAL);

SPAGAIN; 
FREETMPS;
LEAVE;

if (croak_on_error && SvTRUE(ERRSV))
    croak(SvPVx(ERRSV, n_a));

}

main (int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{

char *embedding[] = { "", "-e", "0" };
PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc,&argv,&env);
my_perl = perl_alloc();
perl_construct(my_perl);
perl_parse(my_perl, NULL, 3, embedding, NULL);
PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;


string one = "sub Test{print 'Hello World\n'; my $a = shift; my $b = shift; my $c =shift; my $d = shift; my $e = shift; my $f = shift; my $g = shift; my $h = shift; my $i = shift; my $j = shift; my $k=shift; my $l=shift;print $a; print $b; print $c; print $d; print $e; print $f; print $f; print $g; print $h; print $i; print $j; print $k; print $l;} ";

    perlScript += one ; 


    /* Done with perl script to be executed */
    my_eval_sv(TRUE); 

    PL_perl_destruct_level = 1;
    perl_destruct(my_perl);
    perl_free(my_perl);
    PERL_SYS_TERM();

}
```