# Sample C program working but existing multi-thread C++ program is aborting in Perl_sv_upgrade in Perl 5.16.0

Tags: c, perl, xs

In Perl 5.16.0 sample C program is working but the existing multi-thread program is aborting in `Perl_sv_upgrade`. Multi-thread program works fine with Perl 5.8.8. The same code works on Linux and Solaris with Perl 5.16.0.

Comparing the `sv` argument value between Linux and Hp-PA shows the `sv` value is `NULL` in case of Hp-PA. Did anybody notice this problem before. Please let me know?

**Linux stack trace after debugging and seeing the `sv` value:**

```
Breakpoint 4, Perl_sv_upgrade (my_perl=0x14fe6400, sv=0x150317a8, new_type=SVt_PV)
    at sv.c:1140
1140    sv.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  Perl_sv_upgrade (my_perl=0x14fe6400, sv=0x150317a8, new_type=SVt_PV) at sv.c:1140
```

**HP-PA stack trace after seeing the sv value while analyzing the abort in gdb:**

```
Thread 3 (system thread 428417):

#3 signal handler called
#4 0xca9825c4 in Perl_sv_upgrade (my_perl=0x40236f10, sv=0x0, new_type=SVt_PV)
    at sv.c:1260
```

Comment: Yes, passing NULL to `sv_upgrade` is bad. Don't do that.

Comment: Using `gdb`'s `bt` might help find where the actual bug is.

Comment: @mob - The code snippet posted by me in the link works but the code which i am using is confidential but similar to the one give in link. I'm suspecting some compiler options OR patches but not sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403729/c-calling-perl-code-eval-sv-not-passing-arguments-to-script

Comment: @ikegami - I'm not passing NULL to sv_upgrade. The sample program posted by me in the link works but a similar code written in our project doesn't work on HPUX and AIX.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403729/c-calling-perl-code-eval-sv-not-passing-arguments-to-script

Comment: @mob - I'm new to Perl code and would need some time on finding the problem. If you know of any Perl developer groups who can help me, can you please suggest?

Comment: @ikegami - I'm new to Perl code and would need some time on finding the problem. If you know of any Perl developer groups who can help me, can you please suggest?

Comment: @yogishaj, well, something is. Again, using `gdb`'s `bt` might help find where the actual bug is.

Comment: If we could see the full stack trace we might be able to get somewhere.  sv_upgrade is definitely getting passed NULL as evidenced by the `sv=0x0` but without a full stack trace we cannot tell what.

Comment: Have you compiled your XS module with -Wall and are you using the correct datatypes for everything? I recall seeing segfaults ( outside the XS module in question ) with a NULL-pointer argument on a legacy XS module that was using int instead of STRLEN.